# Mysql performance on a wildcard search

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a performance difference between these two queries ?

1) Select * from table;

2) Select * from table where column like '%';

Both the queries return me the same result set.

Comment: obviously simply "select * from table" is faster than other one

Answer (score 1):

If both return the same results, then the `LIKE` query is almost certainly less efficient, because it has to get the same results from the database *and* check the `LIKE` clause, even though it doesn't do anything.

That said, you should benchmark it yourself and see if it makes a difference. It's hard to think of a situation where both would be valid queries though.

Comment: Thanks. Actually in my code I want to add an optional filter to a query which when not present returns the entire result set. So if the filter is not provided it will filter on '%' else it will filter on the value provided. Creating the query dynamically is not an option. Hence I wanted to make sure that I am not impacting performance by implementing it that way.

Comment: @V123456 In that case, I suggest trying it with a large amount of data (resembling the data you expect to put in your table) and see if the performance is acceptable. It's hard to give general advice about this because it depends on your table and your performance requirements.

Comment: oh ok.. Will try doing that. Thank you

Comment: Actually, the predicate does do something... it's equivalent to a "`column is not null`" predicate. (A row with a NULL value in that column will not be returned by the second query.) So there is a significant difference; it's only in the special case where we are guaranteed that column IS NOT NULL that we can claim to guarantee that the resultsets from the two queries are equivalent.

Comment: Thanks. @spencer7593 Assuming that column does not have null values and it returns the same result set, will the performance differ compared to doing a select * from table?